# I cheated to make redux work, how does this work?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux

So I'm learning react but I am no javascript fan so I'm using typescript. Because of that I try to type things but it seems like using `any` is always the cheat way out. Here's my container:

```
interface UserProfileRouteProps {
  userId: string
}

export function mapStateToProps(state: StoreState, props: RouteComponentProps<UserProfileRouteProps>) {
  let userId: number = parseInt(props.match.params.userId)
  const user = state.users.find(u => u.id === userId)

  return {
    id: userId,
    name: user.name,
    foo: user.foo
  }
}

export function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch: Dispatch<actions.UserProfileActions>, props: RouteComponentProps<UserProfileRouteProps>) {
    let userId: number = parseInt(props.match.params.userId)
  return {
    onFoo: () => dispatch(actions.foo()),
    onDelete: () => dispatch(actions.delete(recipeId))
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(UserProfile as any)
```

Here's the component

```
export interface UserProfileProps{
  id: number
  name: string
  foo: IFoo
  onFoo?: () => void
  onDelete?: () => void  
}

export class UserProfile extends React.Component<UserProfileProps, void>{
```

Now I wanted my `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` to be strongly-typed and have a return type of `UserProfileProps` but I couldn't do that because `connect()` threw an error:

`error TS2345: Argument of type 'typeof UserProfile' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentType<UserProfileProps & { onFoo: () => { type: string; }; onDelete: () => ...'`

so my cheat after googling was to go `UserProfile as any`.

What's actually happening here? Am I doing this right? Should I have separate container props and component props? I was trying to make the component unaware of the routing.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the generic form of connect

```
export default connect<{}, {}, UserProfileProps>(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(UserProfile);
```

Comment: This gives me the error `error TS2345: Argument of type '(state: StoreState, props: RouteComponentProps<UserProfileRouteProps>) => { id: number; name: st...' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MapStateToPropsParam<{}, UserProfileProps>'.`